# JQuery - Delete table row if delete button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a basic database that's intended to only be stored in memory as practice in Javascript. Each new row gets it own corresponding delete and edit buttons. My problem now is how to get these delete buttons to work, that when you click on one it deletes it's row. Here is my code at this moment:

**Javascript**

```
function onload(){
$("#addbutton").on("click",addRow);

$(".delete").onclick(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});

    var i = 1;

    function addRow(){        
        var newRow = "<tr rowID='" + i + "'>"+"<td><div>"+$("#namebox").val()+
                    "</div></td>"+"<td><div>"+$("#surnamebox").val()+"</div></td>"+"<td><div>"+$("#agebox").val()+"<td><div><button id='" + i + "' class='delete' name='delete'type='button'>DELETE</button></div></td>"+"<td><div><button class='edit' name='edit'type='button'>EDIT</button></div></td><td><p>"+ i + "</p></td></tr>"; //Adds the row with content and 
                            // buttons
        $(newRow).appendTo("#maintable"); //Append the new row
            // to the table
        // Next three commands clear the input boxes
        $("#namebox").val('');
        $("#surnamebox").val('');
        $("#agebox").val('');
        // Add to the numer of rows in the table
        i++;
    }// addRow END
};
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Memory-Only Database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
<div id="header">
    <h2>Memory-Only Database</h2>
</div>
<div id="input-table">
<table id="maintable" style="width: 60%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th id="buttons1">buttons1</th>
        <th id="buttons2">buttons2</th>
        <th id="counter">counter</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="namebox" name="name" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="surnamebox" name="surname" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="agebox" name="age" type="number" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="addbutton" name="add" type="button">ADD</button> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
 background-color: darkcyan;
}

div#header{
 position: relative;
 left: 30em;
 width: 18em;
 text-align: center;
}
div#input-table{
 width:50em;
}

table,th,tr,td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;    
}

td{
text-align: center;
}

th#buttons{
width: inherit;
 }
```

Comment: where you want to place delete button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use event delegation for delete button. since you are adding button dynamically.

```
$(document).on("click",'.delete',function(){

   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

```js
function onload(){
$("#addbutton").on("click",addRow);


    var i = 1;

    function addRow(){        
        var newRow = "<tr rowID='" + i + "'>"+"<td><div>"+$("#namebox").val()+
                    "</div></td>"+"<td><div>"+$("#surnamebox").val()+"</div></td>"+"<td><div>"+$("#agebox").val()+"<td><div><button id='" + i + "' class='delete' name='delete'type='button'>DELETE</button></div></td>"+"<td><div><button class='edit' name='edit'type='button'>EDIT</button></div></td><td><p>"+ i + "</p></td></tr>"; 
//Adds the row with content and 
                            // buttons
        $(newRow).appendTo("#maintable"); //Append the new row
            // to the table
        // Next three commands clear the input boxes
        $("#namebox").val('');
        $("#surnamebox").val('');
        $("#agebox").val('');
        // Add to the numer of rows in the table
        i++;
    }// addRow END
};


$(document).on("click",'.delete',function(){
    
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color: darkcyan;
}

div#header{
 position: relative;
 left: 30em;
 width: 18em;
 text-align: center;
}
div#input-table{
 width:50em;
}

table,th,tr,td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;    
}

td{
text-align: center;
}

th#buttons{
width: inherit;
 }
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
<div id="header">
    <h2>Memory-Only Database</h2>
</div>
<div id="input-table">
<table id="maintable" style="width: 60%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th id="buttons1">buttons1</th>
        <th id="buttons2">buttons2</th>
        <th id="counter">counter</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="namebox" name="name" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="surnamebox" name="surname" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="agebox" name="age" type="number" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="addbutton" name="add" type="button">ADD</button> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `onclick` method in jQuery, use [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead.

```js
$(".delete").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried your code, did not work in my script for some reason. I think for some reason it does not detect that I click on the delete button

Comment: @Daniel, yes. You add the buttons through JS, thus the event handler doesn't know about buttons, that is added after the handler creation. Use event bubbling to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can delete row .... during adding new row give that row an id and call an onclick function during delete.

```js
 function deleterow(id){
     $("#newrow-"+id+"").remove();
}
function onload(){
$("#addbutton").on("click",addRow);


var i = 1;

function addRow(){        
    var newRow = "<tr id='newrow-"+i+"'>"+"<td><div>"+$("#namebox").val()+
                "</div></td>"+"<td><div>"+$("#surnamebox").val()+"</div></td>"+"<td><div>"+$("#agebox").val()+"<td><div><button id='" + i + "' class='delete' name='delete' type='button' onclick='deleterow("+i+")'>DELETE</button></div></td>"+"<td><div><button class='edit' name='edit'type='button' >EDIT</button></div></td><td><p>"+ i + "</p></td></tr>"; //Adds the row with content and 
                        // buttons
    $(newRow).appendTo("#maintable"); //Append the new row
        // to the table
    // Next three commands clear the input boxes
    $("#namebox").val('');
    $("#surnamebox").val('');
    $("#agebox").val('');
    // Add to the numer of rows in the table
    i++;
}// addRow END

};
```

```css
body{
 background-color: darkcyan;
}

div#header{
 position: relative;
 left: 30em;
 width: 18em;
 text-align: center;
}
div#input-table{
 width:50em;
}

table,th,tr,td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;    
}

td{
text-align: center;
}

th#buttons{
width: inherit;
 }
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
<div id="header">
    <h2>Memory-Only Database</h2>
</div>
<div id="input-table">
<table id="maintable" style="width: 60%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th id="buttons1">buttons1</th>
        <th id="buttons2">buttons2</th>
        <th id="counter">counter</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="namebox" name="name" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="surnamebox" name="surname" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="agebox" name="age" type="number" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="addbutton" name="add" type="button">ADD</button> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```